# Criei uma função para receber uma estrutura, porém ela sempre retorna 0, alguém consegue me ajudar?

Tags: c, funções, struct

Estrutura:

```
typedef struct entrada{

    int M;
    long int Nmax;
    double a0, a1, a2, a3, a4, a5;
    double A, B, e1, e2;
}valor;
```

Função:

```
double FuncaoDada(struct entrada valor, double x)
{
    double resultado;
    resultado = ((valor.a0)*(cos((valor.a1)*x))) + ((valor.a2)*(sin((valor.a3)*x))) + (exp(valor.a4*x)) + (valor.a5);
    return resultado;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Você atribuiu o apelido 'valor' para a struct 'entrada' através do typedef, ou seja, toda vez que você escrever 'valor' em seu código, ele vai interpretar como sendo 'struct entrada', e você utilizou 'struct entrada valor' no parâmetro da sua função, com isso, o parâmetro da função foi interpretado como 'struct entrada struct entrada', o certo seria na sua struct você retirar o typedef

```
struct entrada{
    int M;
    long int Nmax;
    double a0, a1, a2, a3, a4, a5;
    double A, B, e1, e2;
};
```

Ou você utilizar 'valor v' no parâmetro da função

```
double FuncaoDada(valor v, double x)
{
    double resultado;
    resultado = ((v.a0)*(cos((v.a1)*x))) + ((v.a2)*(sin((v.a3)*x))) + 
    (exp(v.a4*x)) + (v.a5);
    return resultado;
}
```